# Maximum Number of characters with FCKeditor

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, fckeditor

Have you determined a maximum number of characters allowed in [FCKEditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/)?

I seem to have hit a wall.  It will display the text to be edited, but changes don't get posted back to the server - only the original text gets posted back to the server.  I am assuming that the changed text is not copied back to the hidden input field.

This problem only occurs with large amounts of text.  Smaller lengths of text work just fine.

This may be a limitation of the editor, of javascript or the browser itself.

I realize this may be more suited for a bug report to the FCKEditor project, but the stack overflow community seems really responsive and willing to help.

Edit: I should clarify what I mean by large.  A text field with 60,000 characters is giving us problems.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, If you have found the solution can you please post it.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We haven't - we use it for a web content management system, and have some large pages that it quite happily handles.  There may be a limit on your response size buffer, or something line that on your web server....

Comment: That's good information.  Have you used more than 60,000 characters?

Comment: Maybe not quite that large...  but I'm not going to count every one of them.  I would suspect that if you are trying edit that amount of data with FCKEditor, you really need to check on their support forum.